how can I distance camera according to player speed?
How can I make the camera move further away from the player according to player's speed?
So, the camera is at default distance, but when the player catches a boost (increases speed), the camera smoothly moves further back. When player gradually gets back to normal speed, the camera gradually comes back to default distance.
I'm using UNITY; C# ; Game is at it's very beginning, very open to any suggestions.
This is the camera follow logic I'm using:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothUpwardFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform followTarget;

    [Tooltip("How far above the player the camera should aim, in world units")]
    public float offset = 0f;

    [Tooltip("How gently the camera should accelerate/decelerate — small values are more responsive")]
    public float smoothDampTime = 0.2f;
    
    // Used to ensure camera's speed is continuous, not jerky.
    float _velocity;

    // Update at end of frame, after player character
    // has finished moving in Update or FixedUpdate.
    void LateUpdate() {
        var pos = transform.position;

        // Max ensures we only move up, not down.
        float targetHeight = Mathf.Max(pos.y,  followTarget.position.y + offset);

        // Smoothly chase targetHeight on y axis.
        pos.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(
            pos.y,
            targetHeight,
            ref _velocity,
            smoothDampTime
        );
        
        // Apply smoothed chasing position to
        // this (camera) object's transform.
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}

I moving player with a RigidBody component:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BirdScript : MonoBehaviour


{

public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
public float flapStrength;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * flapStrength;
        }
    }
}


If you're using the code I offered in answer to your previous question, please go back and click the ✅ icon to mark that answer as "Accepted". Do I understand correctly you're following the player on the y+ axis, but you want to pull back on the z- axis? Is your character being moved with a Rigidbody/Rigidbody2D from which we can read a velocity, or can you show us your character control script?

Ok, just marked the check mark on the first question.
Yes, I am using rigidbody on player, I will provide the logic of that on here. Thank you

Use SmoothDamp, very similar to what you are currently doing with the Y axis.
// ...

    // Notice this is now a Rigidbody2D, not a Transform:
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D followTarget;

    // You will need to customize these two values:
    [SerializeField] private float defaultZDistance = 4;
    [SerializeField] private float speedToZDistanceFactor = 1;

    float _velocityZ;

    // Update at end of frame, after player character
    // has finished moving in Update or FixedUpdate.
    void LateUpdate() {
        var pos = transform.position;

        // Max ensures we only move up, not down.
        float targetHeight = Mathf.Max(pos.y,  followTarget.transform.position.y + offset);

        // Smoothly chase targetHeight on y axis.
        pos.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(
            pos.y,
            targetHeight,
            ref _velocity,
            smoothDampTime
        );

        // Smoothly set distance on Z axis.
        float offsetZ = defaultZDistance + followTarget.velocity.x * speedToZDistanceFactor;
        float destinationZ = followTarget.transform.position.z - offsetZ;
        pos.z = Mathf.SmoothDamp(
            pos.z,
            destinationZ,
            ref _velocityZ,
            smoothDampTime
        );
        
        // Apply smoothed chasing position to
        // this (camera) object's transform.
        transform.position = pos;
    }
// ...

